# date in php human readable format

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
<title>Files</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
<?php
$prodnum = $_GET['prodnum'];

            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sp");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
            {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
                $res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product_info WHERE prodnum = '$prodnum'") OR die(mysqli_error($con)) ;  


                            echo '
                                            <table id="table">
                                            <tr>
                                            <td> <h3> Product Information </h3> </td>
                                            </tr>';


                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                                            $prodnum=$row[0];
                                            $farm=$row[1];
                                            $sh=$row[2];
                                            $sdate=$row[3];
                                            $pdate=$row[4];
                                            $edate=$row[5];
                                            $cert=$row[6];
                                            $shsite=$row[9];
                                            $farmsite=$row[10];


                                            echo'<tr>
                                            <td> <b> Product Number:</b> '.$prodnum.'
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td> <b> Farm:  </b> <a class="links" href='.$farmsite.'> '.$farm.' </a>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td> <b> Slaughter House: </b> <a class="links" href='.$shsite.'> '.$sh.' </a>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <td> <b> Date Slaughtered: </b>'.$sdate.' 
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td><b> Date Produced: </b>'.$pdate.' 
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td> <b> Expiration Date: </b> '.$edate.' 
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td> <b> Certified by: </b> '.$cert.' 
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </table>'
                                            ;
                                }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code displays the data from my database. I do not how to display the date in mysql in human readable format. The result of this code is for example 2014-03-04 but I want to display it like March 04, 2013. The data type of the dates are date in the mysql database. 
I only see converting the timestamp data type. How can I do it? How can I also put it in the  and  tag? Thank you.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
date('F d, Y',strtotime($your_date_variable));
```

For more information check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: how do I put the function date inside the tr tag? <tr><td> DATE</td></tr>

Comment: like date('d-m-Y',$sdate);

Comment: This is not the format OP asks for. This won't produce "March 04, 2013" but "04-03-2013"

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Comment: yes but I don't know how to place it inside the td and tr tags.

Comment: <td><b> Date Produced: </b>'.date('F d, Y',strtotime($pdate)).'</td>

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("F d, y",strtotime($pdate));
```

Use php date function to format any date time, and use php strtotime function to convert any string to date. It returns "March 29, 2014"

Comment: Nice, you took the time to construct the format, the OP asks for. Links to reference manuals increase the educative value of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Before you continue, look at the comment on SQL injection**

You can let MySQL do it for you with the [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. Instead of selecting * do something like:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(name_of_datefield, '%M %d, %Y') as slaughterdate, ... FROM ...
```

Or you can do it on the PHP side by using the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```php
date('F d, Y', $sdate);
```

So for your code you could change:

```
$sdate=$row[3];
$pdate=$row[4];
$edate=$row[5];
```

into

```
$sdate = date('F d, Y', $row[3]);
$pdate = date('F d, Y', $row[4]);
$edate = date('F d, Y', $row[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('jS F Y');
```

So in your case u have to do as

```
$date = new DateTime($pdate);
echo $date->format('jS F Y');
```